# How to design a flowchart in R?

Tags: r, flowchart

is there any way to write a flowchart in R markdown to have it as an introduction in the html_output_file?

Comment: Who uses flowcharts anymore?  Better to write clear, well-named, self-documenting code.

Comment: Check out the [`DiagrammeR`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/DiagrammeR/) package

Comment: Not really helpful, @duffymo (esp since this had virtually nothing to do with flowcharting code). Perhaps take a look at http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/docs.html to see why flowchart diagrams might help convey information well.

Comment: I have no doubt that flowcharts convey information.  I was taught how to flowchart in the 70s.  Not that useful for real programmers.  I can't remember the last time I saw one.

Comment: Thank you very much @hrbrmstr

Comment: @duffymo "real" programmers can _actually read_ SO questions (again you totally missed the point of this question and your assertion about the efficacy of flowcharts in programming is woefully sad)

Comment: @hrbmstr - Nope, I just disagree with you about the efficacy of flowcharts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are number of packages which can help do this. [DiagrammeR](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/DiagrammeR/) and [DiagrammeRsvg](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/DiagrammeRsvg/) are two I have used successfully.

You might like to refer to the fairly simple [source](https://github.com/jackwasey/PRISMAstatement) for the package [PRISMAstatement](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/PRISMAstatement/) which implements the standard PRISMA flow chart for systematic reviews using an intermediate [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) format.